# SQL Server Integration Services not showing in SQL Server Configuration Manager

Tags: sql-server

I have already installed the following:

- SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition
- SQL Server Configuration Manager
- SQL Server Management Studio
- Visual Studio Community 2019
- SQL Server Data Tools

Extensions in Visual Studio 2019:

- Microsoft Analysis Services Projects
- SQL Server Integration Services Project

Apparently, I'm supposed to see ***SQL Server Integration Services*** **running** under the SQL Server Services on my SQL Server Configuration Manager but I don't see such application running. I already have successfully installed the applications aforementioned.

[image: I only have the following under my services on my SQL Server Configuration Manager]

Am I supposed to run or start something first? So that I can see it running?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, I didn't install Integration Services yet. I just followed this guide over here. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6635/install-ssis/

Answer (score 0):

Its an option when you installed SQL Dev edition...check the install log to see if it was installed. If not, run the SQL Server installer again and choose it

Comment: Which part does it let you choose? I only chose Basic installation and let it install on my laptop.

Comment: I already solved it. Thanks!